# Eclipse can compile but not in command line(javac)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, compilation, javac

I'd like to know the way to compile a project which has a dependency.

```
package a;
import b.B;
class A{
    B b;
}
package b;
import a.A;
class B{
    A a;
}
```

I have a project which has a dependency like the one seen above.

I tried to compile with `javac`(in `jdk`). I've already used the `-classpath` option, but it doesn't work.

I heard `Apache Ant` supply this and maybe eclipse uses it. So I think there is no reason that it isn't possible only with java compiler.

I'd like to know the way to compile this with `javac` (in command line) and, if you know, how `apache ant` and `eclipse` work together to compile. Could you tell me the reason??

Comment: Could you please post the actual file structure and code... here it seems there's something wrong: classes have a private package visibility but you are using them in different packages... this cannot compile

Comment: I'm sorry that i wrote just what i think....
Here's real code example

package a;
import b.B;
public class A {
 B b;
}


package b;

import a.A;

public class B {
 A a;
}

Comment: We can't see your screen, so we can't know what's going on. What did you do ? (Show us the exact commands you typed). What happened ? (Show us the exact output you got)

Comment: When you are compiling from the command line are you compiling both classes at once? (in the same file, or providing both with the same compile command). If not, javac can't resolve the mutual dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how can Eclipse compile your code.
Mine can only if I modify the class visibility to public:

**a/A.java**

```
package a;

import b.B;

public class A {
    B b;
}
```

**b/B.java**

```
package b;

import a.A;

public class B {
    A a;
}
```

Compiling from the command line is easy then:

```
javac a/A.java b/B.java
```